# How move data in platform-specific code in Xamarin.Forms and run methods?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I faced one problem. I am writing an application that allows you to register. Registration data is in the common code, and the registration method is in the platform code (because the general one does not support it). How to call the registration method from platform codes and transfer data from the common code to it?

Comment: You can use DependencyService.Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Share your sample or provide the full code so that we can help you better.